# dlopen vs linking overhead

Tags: linux, dynamic, linker, dlopen

Suppose I have a library - foo.so . When building my binary (which needs this library), I can either (1) link foo.so , or,  (2) within the program source code, dlopen this library and then call functions provided by this library

Is there any performance difference between (1) and (2) when I call a function from the library? Note that I am aware that there will be different initialization characteristics (like the cost of the dlopen , overhead for first usage of a symbol etc) but in the steady state, are both alternatives equally fast or is one faster?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the library is a shared object (ie some `lib*.so` file) compiled with `gcc -Wall -fPIC -O2` and linked with `gcc -shared` then it is an [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) [Position Independent Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) shared library.

<sup>PIC is a bit more costly on 32 bits x86 -which has few registers- than on 64 bits x86-64 -which has some addressing mode facilitating PIC</sup>

It is the same (in steady state) performance wise if it is `dlopen`-ed or if it is dynamically linked. Because in both cases the real linking is done by the [dynamic linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) (e.g. `ld-linux.so`) sine `libdl.so` is basically a wrapper to the dynamic linker.

<sup>What matters performance wise when called is the code inside the `lib*.so` and it does not change if you `dlopen` it or if you link it.</sup>

Things could be slightly different if the library is *statically* linked `lib*.a`. You could even compile and *link* both the library and the program with the [link time optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_Time_Optimization) ability of recent GCC compilers (compile and *link* with `gcc -flto -Wall -O2`)

Read Drepper's [How to Write Shared Library](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) paper and the [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/) and [Levine's Linkers & Loaders](http://www.iecc.com/linker/) book.

Comment: But doesn't `dlopen` provide extra layer of indirection via pointer?

Comment: Not w.r.t. some shared library (like `libc.so`) which also uses an indirection