# How to identify the shared library, whose functions are currently being executed by an executable

Tags: c++, c, linux, ltrace

An executable file, `a.out`, loads the shared libraries `1.so`, `2.so` and `3.so`. There is a function `func()` implemented in each of the three libraries. When `func()` is invoked, I want to identify, which implementation of `func()` is executed.

I tried `ltrace` on the PID of the executable file. It only lists the `func()` call, but not the shared library.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Two similar questions (but not exact duplicates, IMHO): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538501/linking-two-shared-libraries-with-some-of-the-same-symbols http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079742/same-symbols-in-different-libraries-and-linking-order

Comment: If you know the address of the function, you can look it up in the process memory map (`/proc/<pid>/maps`).

Comment: I agree "not duplicates", but if you know the order that the libraries were passed to the linker, the questions very strongly imply that it will be `func` from the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Using systemtap:

```
probe process("/path/to/1.so").function("func")
{
  printf("%d: 1.so\n", pid());
}       

probe process("/path/to/2.so").function("func")
{
  printf("%d: 2.so\n", pid());
}       

probe process("/path/to/3.so").function("func")
{
  printf("%d: 3.so\n", pid());
}
```

Use it with:

```
sudo -E stap ./func.stap
```

With linux perf:

```
sudo perf probe -x /path/to/1.so func
sudo perf probe -x /path/to/2.so func
sudo perf probe -x /path/to/3.so func
sudo perf top -e probe_1:func,probe_2:func,probe3:func
```